# In web-mode - how to pull closing braces and parenthesis to indentation level of opening line

Tags: emacs, indentation

In most emacs modes, when typing a closing brace at the end of a block, the brace is automatically pulled back to the indentation level of its respective opening line.  For instance, after typing the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // stuff
    }
```

the closing brace is pulled back to the left:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // stuff
}   // <---- pulled back with no additional input
```

When using web-mode, however, this is not the case, at least with the default setup.  The closing brace is not pulled back to the correct indentation until there is certain additional input, e.g. pressing tab or enter while the cursor is on the line of the closing brace.  This doesn't work well with a style of coding where one adds the closing brace before adding any block content, which does work well when coding in C in emacs (specifically, I mean typing "{ enter enter } C-p").  In this sequence, there is nothing to trigger the closing braces to pull back one indent level, so my code looks like this:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
            );
        }
    }
```

unless I add a tab press to that sequence ("{ enter enter } tab C-p").

I know it's just one key, and I could just change my habits, but is there a way to change emacs' behavior instead? I don't see any relevant variables to change in web-mode's [documentation](http://web-mode.org/), but am I missing something?

**Edit:** After learning a lot more about emacs than I ever thought I would, I realize that what I'm looking for is actually a specific feature of cc-mode. In cc-mode, } is bound to c-electric-brace. From the source:

```
(defun c-electric-brace (arg)
  "Insert a brace.

If `c-electric-flag' is non-nil, the brace is not inside a literal and a
numeric ARG hasn't been supplied, the command performs several electric
actions:

\(a) If the auto-newline feature is turned on (indicated by \"/la\" on
the mode line) newlines are inserted before and after the brace as
directed by the settings in `c-hanging-braces-alist'.

\(b) Any auto-newlines are indented.  The original line is also
reindented unless `c-syntactic-indentation' is nil.

\(c) If auto-newline is turned on, various newline cleanups based on the
settings of `c-cleanup-list' are done."
```

So it seems that to get this feature in web-mode, I need to learn some lisp and submit a PR.  That's what I'll be doing, and will submit an answer here if/when I finish.  In the meantime, I'd still love input from anyone who knows more about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did end up submitting a PR with this feature, but the maintainer apparently had the same idea and merged it in himself. It's live as of v14.0.36 (commit [3e74b74](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/commit/3e74b741abf8d3113a67ab6b48fba7fdd404e712)).

As I stated in the edit to my question, c-electric-brace is a key binding, so the effect is immediate. This is more difficult to implement in a situation where it might be easily enabled/disabled, so in web-mode, it is added as a post-command hook. As a result, it takes place *after* blinking the matching parenthesis/brace/bracket if [show-paren-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode) is enabled. Thus there is a short delay.

This effect is enabled when `web-mode-enable-auto-indentation` is set to `t`, as it is by default.  Here is the relevant code (the merged addition, not mine):

```
(when (and web-mode-enable-auto-indentation
           (member this-command '(self-insert-command))
           (member (get-text-property (point) 'part-side) '(javascript jsx))
           (looking-back "^[ \t]+[]})]"))
  (indent-according-to-mode)
  ;;(message "%S" (point))
  (when (and web-mode-change-end (> web-mode-change-end (point-max)))
    (message "post-command: enlarge web-mode-change-end")
    (setq web-mode-change-end (point-max))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `defun` from `web-mode.el` try:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

Comment: This doesn't do the trick, unfortunately, because web-mode already corrects the indentation on RET, so changing the binding on RET doesn't change anything.  It would have to be something bound to }.

Comment: However, your answer sent me down the rabbit-hole of learning about emacs key bindings to functions (two hours ago I knew nothing about lisp - that's changing fast), so I'm figuring out more about what it is I want. So I'd upvote, though my current rep doesn't allow it, for pointing me in the right direction. I'll update my question.